# Unable to unlock account or send transaction using web3.js

Tags: web3js

I'm new to Ethereum Blockchain. I have been trying to send ether using web3.js npm. Here's my code

```
const testnet = `https://ropsten.infura.io/${process.evn.ACCESS_TOKEN}`;
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(testnet));

web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(adminWalletAddress, password, 1000)
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I'm getting an error response -

```
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""
at Object.InvalidResponse (/home/rplanx/Dwip/node_ethereum/web3-1-x-x-contract-transaction/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:42:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/home/rplanx/Dwip/node_ethereum/web3-1-x-x-contract-transaction/node_modules/web3-providers-http/src/index.js:73:32)
at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/home/rplanx/Dwip/node_ethereum/web3-1-x-x-contract-transaction/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:18)
at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/home/rplanx/Dwip/node_ethereum/web3-1-x-x-contract-transaction/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:12)
at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/home/rplanx/Dwip/node_ethereum/web3-1-x-x-contract-transaction/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:12)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/rplanx/Dwip/node_ethereum/web3-1-x-x-contract-transaction/node_modules/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:24)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1106:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:178:19)
```

The response is same for web3.eth.sendTransaction method.
I'm using web3@1.0.0-beta.34. Faced the same issue when using web3@0.20.4

Comment: Try using : `var web3 = new Web3(); web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider(testnet));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This account unlock is valid if you have your keys in the node and this is not the case with Infura. You need to build the transaction and sign it with your private key. Then, you can use `sendRawTransaction` method. Even if Infura is accepting this (which I do not think so) this absolutely insecure to do, because your keys would be in control of someone else.

Comment: yes I have tried sending a raw transaction and it worked. Is there any test node available where this code will run? I mean the unlockAccount code. Thanks in advance

Comment: Then you are on the safe side. If raw transactions work, why are you looking further for a solution that put your keys in someone else hands? My recommendation would be then to run your own node, is the only way your keys are safe.